# Sort by nested Array size inside nested Map

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Hy everyone,
I am having the task of sorting Java Map by descending order of nested Array size/length, but the nested array is inside nested Map. The structure looks like:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> classes = new HashMap<>();
```

I am using lambda and I tried many variations including:

```
classes.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((k1, k2) -> Long.compare(classes.get(k2.getKey()).entrySet().stream().count(), classes.get(k1.getKey()).entrySet().stream().count()))
```

and

```
classes.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((k1, k2) -> Integer.compare(k2.getValue().values().size(), k1.getValue().values().size()))
```

but without any luck. Because of the nature of the data I cannot use another data structure, I have to stick with this one.

Any ideas why my sorting is failing? Thanks for any help, I appreciate it.

Comment: In what sense is the sort failing?

Comment: The sorting is returning the size of the nested Map instead of the Array size inside the nested map.

Comment: There are multiple arrays associated with a key in the `classes` map. You need to aggregate the length values. Sort by average, sum, median? Your examples appear to be sorting on the size of the `map`, not the size of the contained arrays.

Comment: What do you want to print to the console ? All the `ArrayList` sorted by size ? I also mention that [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) isn't an ordered collection.

Comment: I want to print the whole structure in such fashion so that every master key is sorted by the size of the slave key's array size like:

Comment: #MasterKey2:##SlaveKey1:###item1,2,3,4,5
#MasterKey1:##SlaveKey1:###item1,2,3
It's visible that masterKey2 have larger slaveKey ArrayList size, thus it's printed 1st.
Doest that make sense?

Comment: There is no array in your code. Perhaps you are talking about the `List`s…

Comment: That seems simple if the child maps only contain one item each.  But what if the child maps contain multiple items? Which key's value's length would be used to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is under-specified. If the values are `Map`s you can’t just say that you want want to sort by their List’s size as there can be an arbitrary number of lists in each `Map`. Your example given in the comments doesn’t clarify anything as it doesn’t address that issue at all. If you assume that the “slave” maps always have a size of one, you should specify that explicitly. Otherwise, you have to aggregate the sizes.

Further note that there are `static` methods in the `Comparator` interface for creating a comparator based on a property of the element to compare, thus you don’t need to write the code to extract the property twice.

So the solution summing the sizes of the lists may look like

```
classes.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().values()
                                          .stream().mapToInt(Collection::size).sum()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that this aggregation also works if there is only one list in each “slave” map.

Just to be complete, note that specifically for sorting map entries, there are comparator factories in the `Map.Entry` interface which may be used like

```
classes.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(
        m -> m.values().stream().mapToInt(Collection::size).sum())))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

though in this specific case there is no benefit in using it. But if the actual value comparator is simpler, it may improve the code. There’s even a parameter-less variant (i.e. `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`) for the most trivial case that the map values are comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm not stating the obvious, but given the information you've provided, I'm assuming that you're expecting `.sorted()` to sort the original collection.

Because you're using
    `Stream`
The original collection won't be modified.
    `.sorted()`
returns a new collection.  Use the result of that.

Comment: Well, it'll return a sorted `Stream`. It'll still have to be collected into a collection (that supports ordering).

Comment: I am sorting the Map only for the purpose of printing it on the console. I am not intending to modify the original in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Holger I managed to find the proper solution with some more experimenting: what worked for me was

```
classes.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((k1, k2) -> Integer.compare(k2.getValue().values().stream()
                            .mapToInt(Collection::size).sum(),
                    k1.getValue().values().stream()
                            .mapToInt(Collection::size).sum()))
```